# Different order of interpretation depending on the context?

Tags: prolog, order-of-execution

I have the following rules to convert a structure.

```
cmap(predicate(_,Verb,named(N)),[S1,S2]) :-
   next_uid(NewVar), 
   S1 =.. [named,N,NewVar], 
   S2 =.. [Verb,NewVar].
cmap(predicate(_,Verb,Subj),S) :- 
   S =.. [Verb,Subj].
```

the problem is that one rule needs *clauses to be in one order* and there is another rule that needs *clauses to be in another order*, as below :

```
cmap(predicate(_,Verb,Subj),S) :- 
   S =.. [Verb,Subj].
cmap(predicate(_,Verb,named(N)),[S1,S2]) :- 
   next_uid(NewVar), 
   S1 =.. [named,N,NewVar], 
   S2 =.. [Verb,NewVar].
```

how can I do that ?

The problem fields are : **named(N) <=> Subj**

The reason I need different order is that case1(fact) I have value already assigned, in case2(question) I need the variable to be *unbound*, so that it can bind it later.

PS> if it make any difference the rule-call is two steps removed i.e. via another two rules.

---

here the exact usage . the diff is one does skolemization the other dont.
The question variables have to stay un-unified/free, so they can be used as a query.

In addition named(X), have to extracted as its own separate fact when it is in the structure /thats DRS weirdnes i have no control over/.

```
% provides/unifies ID for every Reference variable
skolem([]).
skolem([H|T]) :- next_uid(H), skolem(T). 

convert([],[]).
% use the map to convert any Item
convert(Item-_,R) :- cmap(Item,R).
%processing Questions
convert(drs([], [question(drs(_Refs,Conds))]), Res) :- convert(Conds, Res).
%DRS processing
convert(drs(Refs,Conds),Res) :- skolem(Refs), convert(Conds,Res).
% process list of items                     
convert([H|T],[RH|RT]) :- convert(H,RH), convert(T,RT).
```

---

may be something along the lines of :

```
cmap(predicate(_,Verb,named(N)),[named(N,NewVar),S2]) :- next_uid(NewVar),  cmap(predicate(_,Verb,?X?),S2).
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to distinguish the cases by explicitly verifying whether the 3rd argument of `predicate/3` is bound ("is a variable", to perform the standard language abuse). This is all very outside of first-order positive logic:

```
cmap(predicate(_,Verb,NN),[S1,S2]) :-
   nonvar(NN),
   !,
   cmap_nonvar(predicate(_,Verb,NN),[S1,S2]).
```

Symmetrically (one can actually get rid of the `var(NN),!` as the test and the subsequent committement to the clause have already happened, but I like symmetry if it is not expensive:

```
cmap(predicate(_,Verb,NN),[S1,S2]) :-
   var(NN),
   !,
   cmap_var(predicate(_,Verb,NN),[S1,S2]).
```

**Modifications**: Here we can get rid of one use of "univ", `=../2` (don't use "univ" if you don't need it). Also, it's strange and unbalanced that the second argument is a list in one case and a non-list in the other case. Why not use a list in both cases?

### "nonvar" case

**Possible problem**: for `cmap_nonvar` the second clause executes if the 3rd argument of `predicate/3` does not unify with `named(N)` **as well** as if it unifies with `named(N)`. Is that really wanted?

```
% if the 3rd argument of predicate/3 unifies with named(N)

cmap_nonvar(predicate(_,Verb,named(N)),[named(N,NewVar),S]) :-
   next_uid(NewVar), 
   S =.. [Verb,NewVar].


cmap_nonvar(predicate(_,Verb,Subj),[S]) :- 
   S =.. [Verb,Subj].
```

### "var" case

**Possible problem**: I suppose you do *not* want the second clause here, which is always executed as a second case with `Subj` unbound as `Subj` can be unified with `named(N)`.

```
cmap_var(predicate(_,Verb,Subj),S) :- 
   S =.. [Verb,Subj].

cmap_var(predicate(_,Verb,named(N)),[named(N,NewVar),S]) :-
   next_uid(NewVar), 
   S =.. [Verb,NewVar].
```

### Trick: tag the argument

"tagging" means enclosing a term into another term to be able to write Prolog code more idiomatically.

In this case, one can tag `NN`:

```
tag(X,var(X)) :- var(X),!.
tag(X,nonvar(X)) :- nonvar(X),!.

cmap(predicate(_,Verb,NN),[S1,S2]) :-
  tag(NN,TaggedNN),
  cmap_tag_aware(predicate(_,Verb,TaggedNN),[S1,S2]).
```

`cmap` can then match on the particular form of the passed term:

```
cmap_tag_aware(predicate(_,Verb,nonvar(named(N))),[named(N,NewVar),S]) :-
   next_uid(NewVar), 
   S =.. [Verb,NewVar].

cmap_tag_aware(predicate(_,Verb,nonvar(Subj)),[S]) :- 
   S =.. [Verb,Subj].

cmap_tag_aware(predicate(_,Verb,var(Subj)),S) :- 
   S =.. [Verb,Subj].

cmap_tag_aware(predicate(_,Verb,var(named(N))),[named(N,NewVar),S]) :-
   next_uid(NewVar), 
   S =.. [Verb,NewVar].
```

Comment: hmm.. i see.. that will be alot of code... i have to replicate the same thing for transitive and ditransitive verbs .. ouch..

Comment: it seem it may be easy to preprocess named() as special case and remove it in advance somehow ..!!

Comment: @sten I added a note on tagging. Maybe it helps?